# Attaching Reference navigation properties - Nopcommerce

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nopcommerce

This question is specifically for the EMS nopcommerce. When I look at the EF implementation in EFRepository

https://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Libraries/Nop.Data/EfRepository.cs

I see that the there is a property

```
    protected virtual IDbSet<T> Entities
    {
        get
        {
            if (_entities == null)
                _entities = _context.Set<T>();
            return _entities;
        }
    }
```

I can see the entity is being set to the context. What I can't see is how the reference navigation properties are being set? Any foreign relationships will not be set to the context right??

Comment: What do you mean by setting "the entity" and "the reference navigation properties"? This method only returns an `IDbSet`. It doesn't set anything.

Comment: By default _entities is null so when the property is called the line _context.Set<T>() is executed which "sets" the entity to the context, however any attached (reference navigation properties) for example if T = Customer, then is Customer.Job attached to the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!

It was because not all of my properties were marked virtual, and I was using List instead of Collection.

:)

Answer (score 0):

This construct is just a lazy initialization of the repository's core member: `_entities`, a `DbSet<T>`. It doesn't matter whether `_entities` is initialized there or in the repository's constructor. It just ensures `Entities` will never return null. **No other objects are set yet.**

Not before you execute a LINQ query against `Entities` are entities materialized and attached to the context. For instance

```
var rep = new EfRepository<Customer>();
var customers = rep.Entities.Include(c => c.Job).ToList();
```

*Now* `Customer`s and their `Job`s are loaded from the database and attached to the context.

Comment: Maybe I needed to add more information, when I add an entity to the cache i.e. Customer and its associated Job, I then pull this customer from cache (memory cache) attempt to access the Job and an exception will occur informing me the Job is not attached to the current context...

Comment: Yes, you should have. Even now it's not clear to me what you mean by adding and pulling from cache. Anyway, if you know up front that you need objects *and* their references (or collections) `Include` is better than lazy loading (which you enabled by adding `virtual`), because lazy loading tends to make many database roundtrips.

Comment: I agree, as long as there is an understanding of lazy loading should be ok :)